# sum of X and Y and Z if they are iid random variables

Tags: random-variables

If X and Y and Z are i.i.d. random variables then does this mean they each have the same mean and the same density distribution- if this is the case then they must be the same variable which means they must not be independent . Please explain.

Comment: Having the same distribution does not make them the same variable. Why do you think that? Consider, for example, the probability space $\{ 1,2 \}$ where $\mathbb{P}$ is the uniform distribution, and the random variables $X(\omega)=1$ if $\omega=1$ and zero otherwise, and $Y(\omega)=1$ if $\omega=2$ and zero otherwise. Then $X$ and $Y$ have the same distribution (they are both Bernoulli(1/2)) but they are not the same variable. (In this example they are not independent either; in fact $Y=1-X$. Still, that's not the point of this little illustration.)

Answer (score 1):

Let $X, Y, Z$ be the results of tossing three coloured, but equally-biased, dice.

Clearly $X, Y, Z$ have the same distribution, but are not the same variable.   They may independently have three different values in any instance.